# How to calculate food consumption if all current human suddenly becomes immortal?

Tags: super-powers, immortality, trans-humanism

What if all human currently become immortal? Those who lived at particular fraction of time gain immortality and newborn don't have it .

So the ages of people on earth currently will become constant and are going to stay forever. The new born can grow up to produce normal humans. But the immortal population will stay constant .

The immortal will still need food as usual.

**How to calculate food consumption and with every day increasing population under this scenario?**

**Note:* What happens to immortal if they do not eat is *irrelevant*. Assume that they will still need to eat.

Comment: Is there a way to kill immortals? Can they be harmed?

Comment: no they can't be killed , but they require food for staying active @Piomicron

Comment: You say "the current population becomes constant" but also mention increasing population. Which is it?

Comment: In that case, if an immortal went for say, 8 weeks without food, would they be able to move? What if at this point, somebody beheaded them?

Comment: Theoretically they could still be buried, thrown into volcanoes, thrown into space or tossed into wood chippers.   Also, could people still have children?   Would those children be immortal too?     The question kind of answers itself.   Somebody would figure out a way to kill or permanently disable somebody else and they'd take it from there.

Comment: I've heavily edited your question. Your original post might be closed as too broad. I see one of your question is actually answerable, so I try to rework the post centered on that question. If you do not like my edit, feel free to click [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/revisions/98775/2) and rollback my edit.

Comment: @AmruthA can the immortals reproduce? If yes, what the children be, immortal or mortal?

Comment: @Vylix That question is answered in the question. The newborn will grow up to be normal humans.

Comment: @userLTK Ditto above

Comment: Children born after the Event will grow up... but as I understand it, a 1-month-old baby at the time of the Event will be an immortal 1-month-old forever?  That's harsh, man... harsh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The amount of food needed right now = X.

The population right now = immortal population = Y.

Food per-person = X/Y.

New population at a particular moment = Z.

Food needed at that moment = X(1+Z/Y)

I leave it as an exercise for the reader to use Google to find the the appropriate values.